# Angular2 ViewChild no referencia elementos hijos dentro de un *ngIf

Tags: angular, viewchild, elementref

Tengo el siguiente problema en un componente, necesito acceder a un elemento hijo dentro del componente pero este al estar dentro de un `*ngIf` cuando el componente se inicializa me da una referencia no valida o `undefined` como puedo solucionar este problema, para cuando se muestre el `div` la referencia al componente hijo sea valida

```
@Component({
   selector: 'form-component',
   templateUrl: 'form-component.html' 
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;
  public mostrar: boolean;


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('input', this.input.nativeElement);
  }

  showForm() {
    this.mostrar = true;
    this.input.nativeElement.focus() // Dara error porque no se puedo establecer la referncia al elemento del DOM.
  }

}
```

**form-component.html** (aqui no funciona)

```
<div *ngIf="mostrar">
  <input type="text" #input>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<button (click)="showForm">mostrar</button>
```

Si el elemento referenciado estuviese fuera del `div` con la directiva `*ngIf` no hay ningun problema:

**form-component.html** (esto funciona)

```
<input type="text" #input>
<div *ngIf="mostrar">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<button (click)="showForm">mostrar</button>
```

Entiendo como el contenido no se dibujo al inicializar el componente, pero no se como establecer la referencia luego de creado para cuando se dibuje el elemento que quiero referenciar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no es posible referenciar un child que este dentro de un *ngIf, un workaround típico es usar hidden.

```
<div [hidden]="!mostrar">
     <input #miInput>
</div>
```

Comment: También puedes leer: [https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks] en el apartado AfterView a ver si te sirve.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta asignando un `setTimeout` para esperar a que  angular termine de actualizar la vista y los elementos en cuestion:

```
  showForm(){
    this.mostrar = true;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.input.nativeElement.focus();
    });
  }
```

Lo que pasa con tu codigo es que angular no actualiza la vista justo al momento de reasignar la variable `this.mostrar`, sino que una vez terminada la ejecucion del metodo, procede a actualizar las referencias de los objectos afectados por el cambio. El setTimeout lo que hace es esperar que termine ese proceso para luego que con lleva asignar la variable `input` y luego obtener la ferencia del mismo.